# MVC Contrib and MVC Futures: do they complement or negate each other?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib

Every time I start a new MVC 3 project, I'm not sure whether to ue MVC Contrib or MVC Futures. They've both proved useful in the past and seem to be aiming to achieve the same things in many ways.

Should I use one, the other or both?

Answer (score 2):

Although there is some overlap, I would say that they tend more towards complementing each other.  I say that because MVCContrib exist as community extensions to MVC, while MVC Futures are proposed features that may be included in future versions of MVC.  You may find that there are useful features within the former, that will not appear in the latter.